# UTF8String example for seagull

Tags: linux, unicode

I am trying to test a diameter application using seagull.

In the captured PCAP file I have `3GPP-SGSN-MCC-MNC`, which is defined as `UTF8String`.

In seagull, I defined `UTF8String` in `base_cc.xml` as:

`<typedef name="UTF8String" type="number" size="8" unit="octet"> </typedef>`

in my `ccr-cca.client.xml` I use it `<avp name="3GPP-SGSN-MCC-MNC" value="41308"></avp>`

but this fails in PCRF side. It does not recognize the value as `41308`. I have changed `type=string`, but didn't solve the problem.

What am I missing here? Is there a way to convert a number into a UTF8String?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Officially its not supported yet in Seagull. I have to use `OctetString` for every `UTF8String` values.

[Derived AVP Data Formats in Diameter dictionary](https://sourceforge.net/p/gull/mailman/message/25777207/)

[diameter derived types](https://sourceforge.net/p/gull/mailman/message/31827067/)